# Feature detection for input capture=video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video-capture, capture

I need to use a  field in order to enable Android and iOS users to choose to snap a picture with their camera, I append that input field with jQuery but how can I do feature detection so I show that field only to browsers that need that method instead for e.g. flash or getUserMedia?

Something like,

```
if (navigator.captureFeature) {
 //append the input field
} else {
 //device does not support capture=camera
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: I found this:

https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js

Maybe this helps?

> This looks like what you want:
>
> http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/
>
> ```
> function hasGetUserMedia() {
>   // Note: Opera is unprefixed.
>   return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
>             navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
> }
>
> if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
>   // Good to go!
> } else {
>   alert('getUserMedia() is not supported in your browser');
> }
> ```

Comment: Actually no, this checks for getUserMedia which is unavailable for iOS 6 and Android 3/4 (They use a deprecated <device>(?) implementation to access the camera)

Comment: @user780756 I found a library with flash fallback on github. Maybe this helps.

Comment: flash isn't supported in iOS though, what I am trying to do is fallback to input type=file somehow for these devices